# How can I change the background of NEXT item with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, background, jquery-selectors, parent

I have the following approach but I cannot make it work. I want to remove the background of the following li-tag on mouseover.

My code:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php?id=2"  >Das Hotel</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?id=3"  >Angebote</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?id=4"  >Reservierung</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?id=5"  >Kontakt</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?id=6"  >Anfahrt</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?id=7"  >Rechtliches</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?id=8"  >Impressum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$("#mainmenu ul li a").hover(function() {
$(this).parent().next().find("li").css('background', 'none');
}
```

Here the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bQxJu/2/

Comment: `$(this).parent()` is an `li`. So `$(this).parent().next().find("li")` is not going to find anything.

Comment: Also think you need to change it back, once the hover leaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bQxJu/6/

The JS had an error in it, so I had to fix it. I  also added a "mouse out" event handler to put the background back.  Also, you were setting 'none' to the BG of the LI, but your CSS had the background on the anchor, not the li.

Here's the JS:

```
$("#mainmenu ul li a").hover(function () {
   $(this).closest('li').next().find("a").css('background', 'none');
}, function () {
   $(this).closest('li').next().find("a").css('background', '');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did it now exactly as you wrote it here and compared it with the Fiddle, but on my page it is still not working: http://vorschau9.mierau.de/
How can that be? The divider-graphic on the next li on mouseover should be hidden..

Comment: You have a javascript error.  You're accessing jquery's $, but it looks like $ doesn't exist, which is the case when jQuery is run in "no conflict" mode.  if you change `$(window)` to `jQuery(window)` you'll see the JS error goes away (though the hover methods will still fail because of `$`).  I'm not sure why your jquery library is being set to noConflict mode, but that'd be my hunch.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mainmenu ul li a").hover(function () {
  $(this).parent().next('li').find('a').css('background', 'none');
}, function () {
  $(this).parent().next('li').find('a').css('background', '');
});
```